# How to hit a localhost url from rest assured in a bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: java, docker, rest-assured, bitbucket-pipelines

I've an application where I'm Integrating test cases in the bitbucket pipeline.
My test code should hit the url which I wrote in java using rest assured.
It is working normally without pipeline.

here is the pipeline I've created. 1st step is for running the backend and step 2 is starting the test.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: setup
        image: elixir
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install gcc make
          - cp apps/api/config/dev.secret.exs.txt apps/api/config/dev.secret.exs
          - mix local.hex --force
          - mix local.rebar --force
          - mix deps.get
          - mix ecto.create --quiet
          - cd apps/terminator
          - mix deps.get
          - mix ecto.create --quiet
          - mix ecto.migrate
          - cd ..
          - cd api
          - mix ecto.migrate
          - mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
          - nohup mix phx.server &
          - sleep 15s
        services:
          - postgres
    - step:
        name: Sanity Test
        image: maven:3.3.9
        caches:
          - maven
        script:
          - cd Test/TestAPIFramework
          - mvn  -B clean install 

        services:
          - postgres


definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      variables:
        POSTGRES_DB: '***_**'
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
```

everytime I'm getting connection time out...I think It is not able to make the connection

11:42:55.664 [main] INFO  ApiFramework.User - Hitting URL: http://192.168.1.69:4000

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Every step runs in the new container. If you want to access server, you should so this withing the same step in which you've started this server.